# Twin indices of the form $K = 6 (a n)^b$

Tags: twin-primes

Let  $K \ge 6$  (usually called twin index) be the number between a pair of twin primes, and let $k = K / 6$.

It is easy to see that all $k = n^2$ (where  $n$  is a generic integer) are divisible by  5    (ex.: 25, 100,1225, 3600, 4900, 5625, 44100),   but why are all numbers  $k = n^3$ divisible by 7?
Ex.: 21952, 74088, 4741632, 8365427, 23987543104.

It appears that there are no other numbers of the form  $k = (a n)^b$  with  "$a$"  determined by "$b$" and both of them different from the pairs 5, 2 and 7, 3.

Can someone prove that?